# SSO Sign in to WEB App using windows Active Directory

Tags: node.js, windows, oauth, single-sign-on, passport.js

Is there a way to sign in to Web Application with credentials from active directory on windows?

It should not ask for Username / password instead web app should login as SSO using windows user creds

ADFS, Thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

If you work in an entirely Microsoft shop (meaning domain-joined IIS servers for web services, all your users are logging into AD-joined machines with Kerberos, etc.), then you can use Windows Integrated Authentication (WIA) to log in to the application.

You don't need to look at OIDC or SAML until you need to authenticate a user that doesn't reside in your AD or your shop uses web services that aren't WIA-capable (like Apache or NGINX).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this enterprise-wide single signon (SSO) can be done via a protocol called [SAML 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0), or one called [OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-openid-connect-oauth-flows-scenarios).  Either protocol requires support for the protocol you choose to be built in to your web application.

You didn't mention the tech stack you use for your web application, so it's not possible to give more specific advice. Many tech stacks offer support for these sorts of SSO. Still, developing, testing, and implementing it requires a substantial investment of time. Many software-as-a-service vendors recoup this investment by charging enterprise-level subscription fees for customers who work this way.

Comment: Oops sorry, We are working with React-Node

Comment: With nodejs, use [passport.js](https://www.passportjs.org/)  and, maybe, its [SAML](https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-saml/) "strategy" package. Or one of the Azure AD packages? There are many packages to choose from.

Comment: But is that possible? Will that fetch client ( windows creds ) ?